# Assign a Keyboard key to a button click WINFORM

Tags: c#, winforms, key

I am developing a small application with some buttons and textbox. What I am having problem is assigning a keyboard key (e.g. F3) to a button click.

For example if the user click the button *Cash* the code I wanted it's executed fine, but I want to make more easier instead clicking the button with mouse, I want the user be able to press the key on keyboard. I used the `keydown` event, also `keypress` event of that button, but still nothing.

I tried this keydown event

```
          if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
          btncash.PerformClick()
        }
```

But still nothing

Comment: can you share the code you have written for this? and explain the issue you are facing there?

Comment: You don't need a Mouse click, you need to detect when a Key or combination of Keys is pressed and call the same method that you Button.Click handler calls. If you have inserted code in the Click handler, move it to a method (where it belongs anyway).

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I edited the question(added the code you asked for)

Comment: @Jimi any example code, cause I am new(student)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use F3 function button it's used by OS for activating search. Enter key is fairs  click event on focused control so do not use this also. Implement as suggested below.
In your Main form

Set KeyPreview to True in form load event.
Add KeyDown event handler with the following code

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, 
KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.H)
    {
        btncash.PerformClick();
        //btncash_Click(null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this one now, but still nothing is happening. No errors, not execution of code ,, nothing

Comment: Are you Set KeyPreview = True; in form load?  What key you pressed  I set Control + H key,  is the debugger hit form keydown event?